Why does the determinant of a basis matrix divide the determinant of a modified matrix?
I am studying the properties of determinants in the context of linear algebra and lattice theory and came across an interesting observation. Given a matrix
$$ A = [V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_e, V] $$
where $ V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_e $ form a basis of a lattice in $ \mathbb{Z}^e $, and $ V $ is another vector in the same space, I have read that the determinant of $ A $ divides the determinant of a modified matrix
$$ B = [V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_{i-1}, V, V_{i+1}, \ldots, V_e] $$
which is formed by replacing one of the basis vectors with the vector $ V $.
I understand that the determinants can be interpreted geometrically as volumes of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors. However, I am struggling to understand why the determinant of $ A $ divides the determinant of $ B $.
Could someone provide a clear explanation or proof of this property? Additionally, any insights into the underlying principles that lead to this divisibility would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Write $V = \sum_{i = 1}^e a_iV_i$ with integers $a_i$ and see what happens.

@Tzimmo Yes, I believe that’s the underlying idea, but I’m having difficulty understanding it.

How far have you gotten with a proof?

@Tzimmo $\textbf{Linear Combinations:}$
Since $ V $ can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors $ V_1, \ldots, V_e $, there exist integers $ c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_e $ such that:
$$ V = c_1 V_1 + c_2 V_2 + \ldots + c_e V_e. $$
This means that the vector $ V $ is in the span of the original basis vectors $ V_1, \ldots, V_e $, which connects the two determinants.

Plug this into the determinant of $B$ and simplify.

@Tzimmo So we will get $|B|=|[V_1,\cdots,V_{i-1},c_1V_1+\cdots +c_eV_e,V_{i+1},\cdots,V_e]|$.

Can you use properties of the determinant to simplify this expression?

@Tzimmo we will get the following:  $
|B| = c_1 |[V_1, \ldots, V_{i-1}, V_1, V_{i+1}, \ldots, V_e]| + c_2 |[V_1, \ldots, V_{i-1}, V_2, V_{i+1}, \ldots, V_e]| + \cdots + c_e |[V_1, \ldots, V_{i-1}, V_e, V_{i+1}, \ldots, V_e]|.
$

Very good. Are some of the terms zero, maybe?

@Tzimmon yes all the term except one and we get $|B|=c_i|[V_1,\cdots,V_i,\cdots,V_e] =c_i|A|$. and  thus we are done .thank you very much.
